# Multitennancy by domain or subdomain

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to implement some basic multitenancy where each user can have their own site using a subdomain of my domain (e.g. tenant.mydomain.com), or use their own custom domain with any subdomain (e.g. [www.theirdomain.com](http://www.theirdomain.com) or store.theirdomain.com). On sign-up, they get a subdomain, but could later change to a custom domain. The system needs to find the correct tenant regardless of whether they access the route using the subdomain or domain, and ideally I'd like to use the same routes, controller functions, etc. for both subdomain and custom domain access.

I have the subdomain of my own domain functioning properly with the following:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}' . env('SESSION_DOMAIN')], function () {
  // Tenant-specific routes here
});
```

Each route receives the subdomain and I can look up their tenant accordingly in the corresponding controller method.

The difficulty I'm having is using a custom domain. I can do something like the following...

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{prefix}.{domain}.{suffix}'], function() {
  Route::get('/', function($prefix, $domain, $suffix) {
    return "Domain is: $prefix.$domain.$suffix";
  });
});
```

... but managing three variables for all routes is a bit unwieldy, and I can't use the same controller functions or blade files as with a subdomain as there is a different number of parameters required. I also have the option to not use an array group and allow any domain/subdomain to access the routes and query the domain / subdomain as follows...

```
$current_url = Request::url();
$current_url = str_replace(['https://', 'http://'], '', $current_url);
$subdomain = array_shift(explode('.', $current_url));
// Now look up the tenant based on the domain if is a custom domain or subdomain if it is our domain
```

But, I'm not really sure where that code, i.e. in the controller methods, or somewhere that's more global (where would that be?). It would also make referencing routes in blade files fairly convoluted.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: After some more reading, it appears it may be possible to set config variables in middleware. So, if I created a group of routes with middleware and set a tennant ID variable, does that sound like it would work? Is that dynamic enough that on each request the config variable would be updated appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some preliminary testing, here is the solution I've come up with...

- Create a new middleware class - in the handle function, get the URL with $request->url() and parse it to see if it's a custom domain or a subdomain of my domain. Query the tennant ID based on the subdomain or domain and add it to a config variable using `config(['tennant.id' => $tennant->id]);`
- Create a route group with the middleaware `Route::middleware(['getTennant'])->group(function () { ... });`
- This config variable can be accessed from anywhere, and it seems like it's not cached in a way that causes unanticipated behaviour from my initial testing.

The middleware code I used is...

Here is my middleware code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Tennant;

class getTennant
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $current_url = $request->url();
        $current_url = str_replace(['https://', 'http://'], '', $current_url);
        if (str_contains($current_url, env('SESSION_DOMAIN'))) {
            // This is a subdomain
            $current_url = explode('.', $current_url);
            $subdomain = array_shift($current_url);
            // Look up the appropriate tennant by subdomain here
            $tenant = Tenant::where('subdomain', $subdomain)->first();
        }
        else {
            // This is a full custom domain - look up the tennant based on domain
            $tenant = Tennant::where('domain', $current_url)->first();
        }
        if ($tenant) {
            config(['tenant.id' => $tenant->id]);
        }
        else {
            abort(404);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: The only issue I've encountered is that if I want to generate a route outside of the current tennant scope with the route() function, I have no way of doing that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the full code you used ?

Comment: My code is too long for a comment - I will add it to my answer above.

Comment: Hi, I have created my multi tenant app using tenancyforlaravel which is working fine on localhost. But I am curious how it would behave on hosting. can you tell me do I need to do any thing extra to point domains or sub domains to hosting or it would be handled by the package ?